# Integrating satellite images or maps in a 3d application

Tags: java, 3d, gis, google-earth

I'm creating a 3d application to represent airspace and I'd like someway of visualising an area of the earth specified by a latitude/longitude box.

so I could then have a 2D or 3d visualisation of that area and use it in my application. I don't mind if it's only a 2d image that can be used as the 'ground' in the visualisation.

I'm fairly new to 3d programming and this sort of thing.

From what I understand I need some sort of GIS, google earth seems ideal or OSSIM but my application is in java and is not a web application so I don't think I can use either?

Are their any alternative libraries that would do something similar in Java(using Jmonkey engine)?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Start looking at [NASA WorldWind](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/) Java API which is an open-source, high-performance 3D Virtual globe API and SDK.

You can build a Java-based app using the World Wind framework -- it provides the "google-earth"-like map with APIs to draw whatever you want on the map.

You can browse the gallery of sample applications to get can idea of what you can create.
http://goworldwind.org/demos/

There is also [OpenMap](http://openmap.bbn.com/) but that only supports 2d.

Comment: I thought the NASA worldWind would be exactly what I was looking for, although it seems to only be a sdk? If it has a standalone library or API it's exactly what I need I think. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Worldwind has the low-level [API](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/1.4/docs/api/index.html) but feels more like a SDK.
Want a more-low level API - check out http://geotools.org